# Problem storing JSON data locally and presenting in tableView

Tags: ios, json, swift

I have the following function that loads JSON data into a tableview. While this is a fine solution I would like to decrease the speed it takes to load the table data by downloading the JSON into a local text file that is referenced when exists.

This is what the JSON() function looks like, its purpose is pull data from the API:

```
private func JSON() {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://example/example/example"),
        let sample = value1.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed)
        else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = "example1=\(example)".data(using: .utf8)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
        guard let data = data else { return }
        do {
            self.JStruct = try JSONDecoder().decode([exampleStruct].self,from:data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
                self.createFile(data: Data)
            }
        }
        catch {

            print(error)
        }

        }.resume()
}
```

I am also trying to use the following 3 functions createFile(), getFileURL() and loadData() to store, call and present the JSON data into a  tableView.

This is what I currently from the 3 functions:

```
func createFile(data: Data) {
    let fileURL = getFileURL()
    do {
        try data.write(to: fileURL)
    } catch let e {
        print(e.localizedDescription)
    }
}

func getFileURL() -> URL {
    let fileName = "CacheData"
    let documentDirURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
    let fileURL = documentDirURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName).appendingPathExtension("json")
    return fileURL
}



func loadData() -> Data? {
    let fileURL = getFileURL()
    do {
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
        return data
    } catch let e {
        print(e.localizedDescription)
    }
    return nil
}
```

I also have this in the viewDidLoad:

```
let fileURL = getFileURL()
if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {
    guard let data = loadData() else { return }
        do{
    self.JStruct = try
    JSONDecoder().decode([exampleStruct].self,from:data)
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

catch {

print(error)

  }

}
```

The issue is while the file is being created it is empty. I am having some trouble understanding what the problem is with createFile() ?

Comment: It is better to edit an existing question rather than deleting and re-asking essentially the same thing.  However, your issue seems to be that you never call `createFile` with the data you fetch from the network.

Comment: I apologize, I just thought it would be better to start fresh. Would it be best to call it in getFileURL()?

Comment: No, you need to call it in `JSON` once you have the data from the network

Comment: I am trying to call it by doing `createFile(data: Data)` below `self.tableView.reloadData()` but I get the error cannot convert value of Data.Tyle

Comment: I can't see that in your code, but regardless, the compiler is telling you can't pass the *type* `Data`, you need to pass an instance of `Data`

Comment: I have updated the post, how can an instance be passed?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to fetch the JSON from a file if you can, otherwise fetch it from the network.

To do this you are going to need to fetch it from the network at least once and save the JSON in a local file.

Something like this:

```
func fetchJSON(completionHandler: @escaping (Result<[ExampleStruct]>, Error>) -> Void) {
    if let examples = loadExamplesFromFile() {
        completionHandler(.success(examples))
    } else {
        loadExamplesFromNetwork() { result in
            switch result {
                case .success(let examples):
                    completionHandler(.success(examples))
                case .failure(let error):
                    completionHandler(.failure(error))
            }
        }
    }
}

func loadExamplesFromFile() -> [ExampleStruct]? {
    guard let data = loadData() else {
        return nil
    }
    do {
        let examples = try JSONDecoder().decode([ExampleStruct].self,from:data)
        return examples
    }
    catch let e {
        print(e.localizedDescription)
    }
    return nil
}


func loadExamplesFromNetwork(completionHandler: @escaping (Result<[ExampleStruct]>, Error>) -> Void) {
    guard let url = URL(string: "https://example/example/example"),
        let sample = value1.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed)
        else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.httpBody = "example1=\(example)".data(using: .utf8)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
    if let err = error {
        completionHandler(.failure(err)
    } else {
        guard let data = data else { 
            //TODO: Should call completionhandler with an appropriate error
            return
        }
    do {
        let examples = try JSONDecoder().decode([ExampleStruct].self,from:data)
            completionHandler(.success(examples)
            createFile(data: data)
        }
    }
    catch {
        completionHandler(.failure(error)
    }

    }.resume()
}
```

Then in your `viewDidLoad` you can call it:

```
fetchJSON { result in 
    switch result {
        case .success(let examples):
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 self.JStruct = examples
                 self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```